# Excel crashing problem - How to study why Excel is crashing?

Tags: excel, debugging, crash, office-js, add-in

We are doing Excel JavaScript add-ins development and testing. Excel keeps crashing 1-2 times per day randomly. It may crash with action from JavaScript Pane or without it just using other Excel methods from its ribbon. There is no repeating pattern we have found.

We use Excel Tables, but that's about it. Not even huge tables just some tens or hundreds of lines mostly. One table in a sheet and below 20 sheets. So nothing special. Sometimes pivots and graphs, too. No VBA or COM add-ons installed. 32-bit Excel on 64-bit Windows. On monthly upgrade cycle so latest build and this has been going on since May 2018 so for several months/builds (at least).

This repeats on multiple developers and not a day without a crash. It feels that it is cumulating something, so it does not crash immediately but maybe after 2-3 hours of use. One idea is that could it be related to network change (between home and office)?

So how could we study this if it is our code and Async calls, or if it is something that we could report as  a problem for MS to take a look?

We have already changed the way we do async calls to TypeScript style, but no change.

We are approaching the date when this goes to customer hands...so naturally this must be solved first. So will be thankful for any tips and suggestions.

Sami

Comment: Hello @SamiLahti. Unfortunately it impossible to answer your question without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and to be entirely honest, the problem description is **too broad** as well.  If you could somehow produce a way to reproduce the issue, then we could perhaps have a discussion about how to solve it.

Comment: I have replace the JavaScript tag with the the Office-JS tag, some of the Microsofties follow that.

Comment: Hi  @Rawrplus, Note that in the first place I'm not asking what is wrong, while it would be nice to know I don't think we are even close to solution yet, but I'm asking how people in general study crashing problems to really know what is wrong. What tools and processes are used?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Excel crashing when using a macro. It wasn't the macro because it worked fine on other systems. I tried everything suggested on the forums -- running in safe mode, checking/unchecking 'Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)', disabling add-ons, etc -- nothing worked. However, eventually I found that uninstalling Office 32-bit on a 64-bit version of Windows and reinstalling 64-bit Office fixed the problem -- finally! Now it works flawlessly. I hope this also works for you!